# nested json to ng-repeat doesn't working properly

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

App demo : http://jsfiddle.net/TR4WC/2/

am I missing something? I looped twice to access the 2nd array

```
    <li ng-repeat="order in orders">
        <span ng-repeat="sales in order.sales>
    {{sales.salesId}}
</span>
</li>
```

one extra question : look like I can't do orderBy by salesId in my li because it have access only to the order array.

Comment: What are you trying to make the output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is silly but you are missing something, double quotes at the end of order.sales.

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<li ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <span ng-repeat="sales in order.sales">
        {{sales.salesId}}
    </span>
</li>
```

That works for me.

EDIT: fork of your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6eXs6/

Answer (score 1):

In the Orders object sales isn't actually an array...it's an object where the key 'salesId' overwrites another 'salesId'.

I've replaced it with the following:

```
{
    'orderId': 1,
        'sales': [
            {'salesId': 1},
            {'salesId': 2}

    ]
}, 
{
    'orderId': 2,
        'sales': [
            {'salesId': 3},
            {'salesId': 4}

    ]
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TR4WC/3/)

Comment: A combination of the two.

Comment: do you have any idea how can I sort with the salesId?

Comment: To sort within an order you could do something like: <span ng-repeat="sales in order.sales | orderBy:'salesId':false">.  Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TR4WC/4/

Comment: that's the problem, I want it to be 4 li

Comment: You could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TR4WC/6/ . I used a javascript library called lodash to do the sorting.

Comment: No problem...one thing to note is if you have a lot of stuff going on on the page you might be better off using the sortedSales function to update an array only when orders are updated and then doing an ng-repeat on the array, because now you're re-sorting the value with each digest cycle, but this is fine for a relatively simple page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51000/discussion-between-noob-and-leo)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same name 'sales'.

Change:

```
<li ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <span ng-repeat="sale in order.sales">
        {{sale.salesId}}
    </span>
</li>
```

Comment: Right, but it's a too bad code style, we should avoid it!
In this case just miss double quotes :)

Comment: sorry I'm noob.. how come I didn't notice that

Comment: @ZackYang why you say it's bad? because in array of sales I put the salesId as object ?